# How to use two-dimensions array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, matrix, custom-data-type

So I have this array `var arrayItinerario: Array<Any> = []`  which is intended to hold arrays of type `Itinerario, var temporalArray: Array<Itinerario> = []`

Next, this `arrayItinerario` would later be used to access properties from the struct `Itinerario` from where the array `temporalArray` type comes from.

```
cell.siteLabel.text = "\([arrayItinerario[indexPath.section]][indexPath.row].ubicacion)"
```

The problem is that `arrayItinerario` is not an `Itinerario` type object which make it impossible to access `ubicacion` to make an example
I have tried
`let object = [arrayItinerario[indexPath.section]][indexPath.row] as! Itinerario` 
But the cast throws an error. How can I do to access properties from the arrays `temporalArray`that are inside `arrayItinerario`?

Note: I am using indexPath because I am filling table cells

Comment: I think you just figured out first hand why `Any` should be avoided. You should probably rethink this model design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arrayItinerario: [[Itinerario]] = []

//fill data
var temporalArray: [Itinerario] = []
arrayItinerario.append(temporalArray)

cell.siteLabel.text = "\(arrayItinerario[indexPath.section][indexPath.row].ubicacion)"
```

or

```
var arrayItinerario: Array<Any> = []
var temporalArray: Array<Itinerario> = []

guard let temp = arrayItinerario[indexPath.section] as? Array<Itinerario>{
    return
}

cell.siteLabel.text = "\(temp[indexPath.row].ubicacion)"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked just fine

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation I've used in a few projects:

```swift
import Foundation

class Array2D<T> {

    var cols:Int, rows:Int
    var matrix:[T?]

    init(cols: Int, rows: Int, defaultValue:T?) {
        self.cols = cols
        self.rows = rows
        matrix = Array(repeating: defaultValue, count: cols*rows)
    }

    subscript(col:Int, row:Int) -> T? {
        get{
            return matrix[cols * row + col]
        }
        set{
            matrix[cols * row + col] = newValue
        }
    }

    func colCount() -> Int { self.cols }
    func rowCount() -> Int { self.rows }
}
```

Because it's generic you can store whatever type you like in it. Example for `Ints`:

```swift
// Create 2D array of Ints, all set to nil initially
let arr = Array2D<Int>(cols: 10, rows: 10, defaultValue: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you! It was useful